# Timing and MaxMemoryUsage of Integrate doesn't respect linear properties of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

**BEFORE READING IT IS BEST YOU KNOW THAT FEYRE's ANSWER PROVES MY STATEMENT TO BE *FALSE***

I have the following Integrals:

```
Timing[Integrate[x^2 + x, {x, 0, 1}]]
Timing[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

In the first case I have:

```
{0.009273, 5/6}
```

In the second:

```
{0.00944, 5/6}
```

This means that somehow Mathematica optimizes evaluations in the first case. How does it manage to do this??? Secondly how much is this related to memory usage? Does Mathematica use more memory in the first case or in the second?

**Update on Memory usage**

```
MaxMemoryUsed[Integrate[x^2 + x, {x, 0, 1}]]
MaxMemoryUsed[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Outputs:

```
{0.006281, 5/6}
{0.008078, 5/6}
```

This means that not only it optimizes time but also max memory usage. Why?

*Is it always convenient to write a huge integral instead of more integrals??? This is the question.*

**EDIT: ABSOLUTE TIMING**

Absolute timing proves the opposite:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[x^2 + x, {x, 0, 1}]]
AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Returns:

```
{0.199372, 5/6}
{0.006759, 5/6}
```

Still not what I expected. And this would mean that one would need to find a compromise between time expenditure and memory expenditure?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to see what happens when increasing the number of arguments to sum.

```
    arguments1 = Table[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 200}];
list1 = Table[
   AbsoluteTiming@Integrate[arguments1[[i]], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, 200}];
arguments2 = 
  Table[MonomialList@Normal@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 200}];
list2 = Table[
   AbsoluteTiming@
    Sum[Integrate[arguments2[[j]][[i]], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, 
      Length[arguments2[[j]]]}], {j, 1, Length[arguments2]}];
timings1 = Table[list1[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 200}];
timings2 = Table[list2[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 200}];
```

This is the result.

[image: timing the integrals]

As for memory usage. **EDIT**

```
arguments1 = Table[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 200}];
list1 = Table[
   MaxMemoryUsed@Integrate[arguments1[[i]], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, 200}];
arguments2 = 
  Table[MonomialList@Normal@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 200}];
list2 = Table[
   MaxMemoryUsed@
    Sum[Integrate[arguments2[[j]][[i]], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, 
      Length[arguments2[[j]]]}], {j, 1, Length[arguments2]}];
```

I have an even more terribly nonlinear behavior of the huge integral if compared to the sum of integrals.

[image: memoryusage]

Do you think this is valid in general for any kind of argument?

Comment: What does `AbsoluteTiming[]` give? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html

Comment: I'm about to edit my question, after your comment. @blochwave

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a number of confounding things going on here:
Firstly, there's the fact that rendering an output changes the time something takes to compute:

A fairer way of timing the two would be:

```
RepeatedTiming[Integrate[x^2 + x, {x, 0, 1}];, 2]
RepeatedTiming[Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[x, {x, 0, 1}];,
  2]
```

> `{0.0015, Null}`
>
> `{0.0019, Null}`

With a slightly longer time to compute the separated integrals, as one might expect as there is an additional calculation.

Then there's the way in which `arguments` is presented,

```
arguments1[[1]]
```

> `1+x+O[x]^2`

Which is given (and integrated) as:

> `SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1}, 0, 2, 1]`;

Fixing this by adding `//Normal` to the line, significantly impacts the results:

```
arguments1 = Table[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 200}]//Normal;
arguments2 = Table[MonomialList@Normal@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 200}];//Normal
```

Without `//Normal`:

[image]

With `//Normal` on `arguments1`:

[image]

With `//Normal` on both `arguments1` and `arguments2`:

```
l1 = LinearModelFit[timings1, x, x] // Normal;
l2 = LinearModelFit[timings2, x, x] // Normal;
Show[ListPlot[{timings1, timings2}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[{l1, l2}, {x, 0, 200}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Purple}, {Thick, Red}}]]
```

[image]

As you can see, in this situation both grow about approximately linearly, and the integral calculated together is nominally faster as expected.

This also more or less fixes the `Memory` issue, though as always with such things there are anomalies

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Feyre just for a matter of clarity would you kindly label your plots?

Comment: To complete the answer you should also add results about MaxMemoryUsed.

Comment: @MirkoAveta What is the code you used for that?

Comment: I'll add the code in a moment.

Comment: would you also add the code you used to the integrals with SeriesData?

Comment: @MirkoAveta That should be it.

Comment: Absolutely! You really eliminated a terrible doubt I was carrying with me since I began using this software!!